# CSS matrix3d causing jagged edges in Chrome but fine in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve smooth edges on an image while using `transform: matrix3d()` with as much cross browser support as possible.

This issue was occuring for me in Firefox too until I used `filter: blur(1px);`

I have tried the following CSS with the respective browser layout engines e.g. `-webkit` and `-moz`:

- `backface-visibility: hidden;`
- `filter: blur(1px);`
- `outline: 1px solid transparent;`
- `will-change: transform;`
- `background-clip: content-box;`

**Snippet/HTML & CSS:**

```css
.bg {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506782081254-09bcfd996fd6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&h=500&q=60');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.target {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(20%, 40%) rotate(0deg) matrix3d(0.331247, -0.014293, 0, 0.000104105, -0.0553603, 0.646191, 0, 0.0000782059, 0, 0, 1, 0, -119.275, -29.721, 0, 1);
  -webkit-transform: translate(20%, 40%) rotate(0deg) matrix3d(0.331247, -0.014293, 0, 0.000104105, -0.0553603, 0.646191, 0, 0.0000782059, 0, 0, 1, 0, -119.275, -29.721, 0, 1);
  -moz-transform: translate(20%, 40%) rotate(0deg) matrix3d(0.331247, -0.014293, 0, 0.000104105, -0.0553603, 0.646191, 0, 0.0000782059, 0, 0, 1, 0, -119.275, -29.721, 0, 1);
  -o-transform: translate(20%, 40%) rotate(0deg) matrix3d(0.331247, -0.014293, 0, 0.000104105, -0.0553603, 0.646191, 0, 0.0000782059, 0, 0, 1, 0, -119.275, -29.721, 0, 1);
  -ms-transform: translate(20%, 40%) rotate(0deg) matrix3d(0.331247, -0.014293, 0, 0.000104105, -0.0553603, 0.646191, 0, 0.0000782059, 0, 0, 1, 0, -119.275, -29.721, 0, 1);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  filter: blur(1px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  outline: 1px solid transparent;
  will-change: transform;
  -webkit-background-clip: content-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/6w6Fww9/ps-standard.png" class="target">
</div>
```

**Firefox Example:**

[image: Firefox smooth edges]

**Chrome Example:**

[image: Chrome jagged edges]